# Spring boot Custom Validator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I try to implements custom validator, in Spring boot 3 and java 17,
to validate string date, but I type mismatch issue for

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ...)
```

This is my code:

DateValidation.java

```
@Target( {ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateValidator.class)
public @interface DateValidation {
    public String message() default "Invalid color: must be RED, GREEN or BLUE";
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

DateValidator.java

```
public class DateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateValidation, String>
{
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String stringDate, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        .....
    }
}
```

In the pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The error on `@Constraint(validatedBy)` is :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<DateValidator> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>[]
```

Comment: Let me guess you are using Spring Boot 3 and decided to add `javax.validation` instead of using `spring-boot-starter-validation`. Spring Boot 3 uses the JakartaEE  classes not the JavaEE classes. Remove the `javax.validation` one and just use `spring-boot-starter-validation` and import the `jakarta.validation` classes instead of `javax.validation`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but like I wrote in the question I use spring-boot-starter-validation e jakarta .

Comment: Apparently you don't as another dependency is added else you would have the proper classes and no errors. Add your dependencies to the question (your pom.xml or build.gradle). Remove the `hibernate-validator` dependency that is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency,.

Comment: You are absolutely right I had a javax validation dependency in the pom that I completely forgot about.
Thank you very much for your answer, if you formulate it in an Answer I'll put it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally comes from the fact that there is a `javax.validation` dependency lingering in your dependencies. Spring Boot 3 supports the JakartaEE API and not the JavaEE API (as that isn't being developed any further and moved to JakartaEE).

Make sure that you are only adding the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. That includes all needed dependencies (both the API as well as the implementation in the form of `hibernate-validator`).

Check your own `pom.xml` if there are no `javax.validation` dependencies lingering around. If they aren't in your own dependencies they might be pulled in by other, incompatible dependencies. Getting those can be figured out using `mvn dependency:tree`.

Finally make sure you are only using the `jakarta.validation` packages in your code and not mixing both `javax.validation` and `jakarta.validation`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom validator in Spring Boot involves several steps. Let's go through the process step by step:

1. **Create a Custom Validation Annotation:**

Start by creating a custom annotation that will be used to mark fields for validation.

```java
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidator.class)
public @interface CustomValidation {
    String message() default "Custom validation error message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

2. **Implement the Validator:**

Create the `CustomValidator` class that implements the `ConstraintValidator` interface. This is where you define your validation logic.

```java
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomValidation, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // Implement your validation logic here
        // Return true if the value is valid, false otherwise
    }
}
```

3. **Using the Custom Validator:**

Now, you can use the custom validator in your Spring components (such as DTOs or entities).

```java
public class MyDTO {
    @CustomValidation
    private String customField;

    // Other fields, getters, setters
}
```

4. **Integrate with Spring Boot:**

Make sure your Spring Boot application is set up to perform validation. This usually involves enabling validation in your application configuration.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;

@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

5. **Using the Custom Validator in a Service/Controller:**

Now, when you use your custom annotation on a field in your DTO, Spring Boot's validation mechanism will automatically invoke your custom validator.

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/validate")
    public ResponseEntity<String> validate(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO myDTO) {
        // Your controller logic here
    }
}
```

That's it! You've created a custom validator in Spring Boot. Remember to implement your actual validation logic inside the `CustomValidator` class. Also, make sure you have the necessary validation dependencies in your project's build file (`javax.validation`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't answer my question at all. It seems generate by chatgpt or similar.

Comment: From spring boot 3.x `javax.`  packages was replaced by `jakarta.`